# libcURL TLS SMTP working but not actually sending

Tags: ssl, smtp, libcurl

So, I'm trying to get smtp-tls.c to work (on VC++) and for the life of me I can't. I only managed to get it to send an email on the first try. After that, the code completes with no errors and yet it doesn't finally send the email.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587/
*   Trying +++.+++.+++.+++...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to smtp.gmail.com (173.194.76.108) port 587 (#0)
< 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o107sm45550896wrc.63 - gsmtp
> EHLO ++++++++++
< 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [+++.+++.+++.+++]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-CHUNKING
< 250 SMTPUTF8
> STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ../cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / +++.+++.+++.+++
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=smtp.gmail.co
m
*  start date: Dec 13 14:11:54 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Mar  7 13:03:00 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "smtp.gmail.com" matched cert's "smtp.gmail.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> EHLO ++++++++++
< 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [+++.+++.+++.+++]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-CHUNKING
< 250 SMTPUTF8
> AUTH LOGIN
< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
> YjN0M2xnZXVzZUBnbWFpbC5jb20=
< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
> VW5kM3J0NGtpbmc=
< 235 2.7.0 Accepted
> MAIL FROM:<++++++++++@+++++++++.+++>
< 250 2.1.0 OK o107sm45550896wrc.63 - gsmtp
> RCPT TO:<++++++++++@+++++++++.+++>
< 250 2.1.5 OK o107sm45550896wrc.63 - gsmtp
> RCPT TO:<++++++++++@+++++++++.+++>
< 250 2.1.5 OK o107sm45550896wrc.63 - gsmtp
> DATA
< 354  Go ahead o107sm45550896wrc.63 - gsmtp
< 250 2.0.0 OK 1516030190 o107sm45550896wrc.63 - gsmtp
* Connection #0 to host smtp.gmail.com left intact
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: The mail is accepted by the mail server: `250 2.0.0 OK 1516030190 o107sm45550896wrc.63 - gsmtp`. It might still be that the mail gets classified as spam and is thus put into the relevant folder automatically. Or it might be that the target mail server (i.e. from the rcpt domain) does discard the mail since it looks like spam.

Comment: The first email that went through is in my sent items and was received by the recipient. The others are neither in the sent folder of the sender nor in the spam folders or the recipient. Wouldn't the sender be seeing this as a sent item regardless of whether it was received as spam?

Comment: Could it by that I was using the same message ID?

Comment: Yes, that might be a reason. But I cannot say for sure that it is the primary reason. I can only say that gmail has accepted the mail.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not change the message ID I recall seeing that Gmail will think of it as the same message. Change the message-id.

Also try this service as troubleshooting: https://www.mail-tester.com/

It will create an e-mail address that you can try to send to and then it will analyze the e-mail's properties that might indicate spam (or other problems that might cause your issues). If you have too many red flags the e-mail might be seen as spam (or even be discarded), but in this case message ID is probably your culprit. Once your mail passes the mail-tester your next step could be sending to an account at a service like Gmail.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, it was the message ID. I changed it and now it works fine.